# Inputting the character onto a map

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def board10():            
    from random import randint
    coins = 0
    board = []
    charac = []
    for i in range(10):
        row = []
        for j in range(10):
            row.append('O')
            charac[x][y] = 'x'
        board.append(row)



    def print_board(board):
        for row in board:
            print (" ".join(row))

    print ("Let's play Treasure Hunt!")
    print_board(board)
    print ("Total Coins:", coins)
    def random_row1(board):
        return randint(O, len(board) - 1)
    def random_row2(board):
        return randint(O, len(board) - 1)
    def random_col1(board):
        return randint(O, len(board[0]) - 1)
    def random_col2(board):
        return randint(O, len(board[0]) - 1)

    left_across1 = random_row1(board)
    right_across1 = random_row2(board)
    up_vertical1 = random_col1(board)
    down_vetical1 = random_col2(board)

    for turn in range(10):
        left_across2 = int(input("How many moves LEFT of the grid would you like to go?:"))
        right_across2 = int(input("How many moves RIGHT of the grid would you like to go?:"))
        up_vertical2 = int(input("How many moves UP of the grid would you like to go?:"))
        down_vertical2 = int(input("How many moves DOWN of the grid would you like to go?:"))

        if left_across2 == left_across1 and  right_across2 == right_across1 and up_vertical2 == up_vertical1 and down_vertical2 == down_vertical1:
            print ("Congratulations! You landed on a Treasure Chest!")
            coins + 10
            break
        else:
            if (left_across2 < 0 or left_across2 > 8) or (right_across2 < 0 or right_across2 > 8) or (up_vertical2 < 0 or up_vertical2 > 8) or (down_vertical2 < 0 or down_vertical2 > 8):
                print ("Oops, that's not even in the grid. Try Again")

            else:
                print ("Turn", turn + 1 )
                print_board(board)
                print ("Total Coins:", coins)


choice = "";
while loop ==1:

    print ("Menu")
    print ("a.) Play the Game")
    print ("b.) Quit the Game")

    print ("")
    choice = input("Select an option = ")
    loop =0

    if choice == 'a':
        print("You have selected to Play the Game")
        print("Select which size grid you would like to play")
        print("1.) 8 x 8")
        print("2.) 10 x 10")
        print("3.) 12 x 12")
        choice=input("Select an option = ")
        if choice =='1':
            board8()
        elif choice == '2':
            board10()
        elif choice == '3':
            board12()
        else:
            print("You've picked an invalid choice")
            loop ==1
    elif choice == 'b':
        print("You have selected to Quit the Game")
        quit()

    else:
            print("You've Picked an invalid Choice")

            loop==1
```

I am currently trying to make a treasure island game whereby the code prints out a 10x10 (trying to get this one to work first and then implement the rest of the sized maps) with an X in the bottom left of the map. The user then tells the program how many positions it wants to move the character up , left, right, and down and it then moves.

It should also have randomly hidden coins in it to allow the character to gain points.

Currently I cannot get the board to print with the X on the board. As it is now it returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*file Root*/Controlled Assessment (1).py", line 91, in <module>
    board10()
  File "*file Root*/Controlled Assessment (1).py", line 17, in board10
    charac[x][y] = 'x'
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the line

```
charac[x][y] = 'x'
       ^
```

When you index a list, as you're doing here, you should be using something that evaluates to a number. For example, if you have a variable named `lst` which holds the value `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (a list of 5 numbers), then `lst[0]` is `1`, `lst[3]` is `4`, and so on. In addition to using a literal number, you can also use a variable which holds a number, like if `foo` is defined as `2` (which you might do with the code statement `foo = 2`), then `lst[foo]` is `3`. This is what you're trying to do in your code, using the value stored under `x` to index the list `charac`. However, you never actually put a number in `x`, so Python doesn't know what to do with it. That's why you're getting this error.

A very simple program which reproduces this error is

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(lst[x])
```

A simplistic way to fix this program would be by changing it to the following:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = 2
print(lst[x])
```

In the future, if you try reducing your program to the smallest possible example that gives the error, one like what I just showed, it will become easy for you to find many of the errors you get.

Comment: Thanks David for your response, appreciate it. Thanks for your edit too! Answered the question I had.

Comment: Could you take a look now. When I try to run the code I am getting this error:

Code: 
from random import randint
    coins = 0
    board = []
    charac = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    for i in range(10):
        row = []
        for j in range(10):
            row.append('O')
            charac[1][1] = 'X'
        board.append(row)


Error:
 File "*File Root*/Controlled Assessment (1).py", line 91, in <module>
    board10()
  File "*File Root*/Controlled Assessment (1).py", line 17, in board10
    charac[1][1] = 'X'
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Alternatively do you have an email I could possibly get some support from you with?